# T-shirt says "Get out of my …" (help me read the last word)

Tags: handwriting

[image: T-shirt saying "Get out of my …?…"]

I do not understand the last word. Can someone write it in plain text?

Comment: Grill - http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grill

Comment: This is more of a graphics design question. It's certainly not about the English language.

Comment: @Janus Alas that in today's post-scriptorial world  decoding even the most basic of cursive hands should be relegated to bespectacled palaeographers  muttering to themselves in dead languages!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The last word is "Grill", written in cursive.

In this context, it means "Get out of my face" (which, in turn, means "Go away").

"Grill" is not generally a synonym for "face" -- but works as a synonym in this context: It's original meaning was the grill (or, more properly, grille) of a car. From this, "grill" came to be used to refer to dental braces or other visible orthodontia (such as gold tooth caps). And from there it gave rise to the meaning in your photograph.

Answer (score 2):

The last word is "Grill". The "r" is a form of the letter which only appears in handwriting (or typefaces which are supposed to resemble handwriting like this one), and not everyone writes them that way.